# How to push a custom variable to GA using dataLayer

Tags: google-analytics

I need to push a custom variable to GA ( _setCustomVar ) using the dataLayer. I have read multiple posts on the subject, and they mention the More Options -> Custome Variables when setting up the Google Analytics tag (I assume they are talking about what is now called Classic Google Analytics, because Universal Analytics does not have a More Options).

The thing that is missing in all those posts, is what Track Type do I choose for that?? There is Pageview, Event, Transaction, etc.

Thank you,
Michel

Answer (score 1):

Custom Var is only applicable to Classic Google Analytics under GTM.

If you are using Universal Analytics then you'll need to use Custom Dimensions and not Custom Variables.

You'll first need to configure the Custom Dimension in Admin > Property Level > Custom Definition > Custom Dimensions

Then you can easily pass any value in this Custom Dimension slot using GTM "More options"

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the CustomVar independedly.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 
1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
'Section',           // The top-level name for your online content categories.  Required parameter.
Life & Style',  // Sets the value of "Section" to "Life & Style" for this particular aricle.  Required parameter.
3                    // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
]);
```

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Comment: I am using GTM. No _gaq.push.

Comment: Gotcha, assuming you always want a pageviews on every page, I would add it to that.